# cant associate an sf::Renderwindow to a different one

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a class called stickyNotes, and in it I have a variable - `sf::RenderWindow windowPaint`, I want to assign that variable a window that I pass in with the constructor. I tried declaring the variable as a pointer and passing the window's address, but then I couldn't use its functions or do anything with it.

Whenever I try doing that I get the error:

> sf::RenderWindow::operator=(const sf::RenderWindow &) (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

The class:

```
 class stickyNotes
{
private:
    sf::RenderWindow* windowPaint;
    void someFunction();
    .....
    .....
public:
    stickyNotes(sf::RenderWindow);
    ......
    ......
    ~stickyNotes();
};
```

The constructor:

```
stickyNotes::stickyNotes(sf::RenderWindow wnd) {

   this->windowPaint = &wnd;
}
```

someFunction()

```
void stickyNotes::someFunction() {
    ....
    windowPaint.draw(someSprite); <--- doesn't work when I use a pointer in windowPaint
}
```

Comment: *"I tried declaring the variable as a pointer and passing the window's address"* - you were on the right path, show us how that didn't work instead. The error message here tells you that making a copy of `sf::RenderWindow` is forbidden. You **have to** use a pointer/reference.

Comment: I used a pointer, but the thing is, When I tried to use the functions of `sf::RenderWindow` it wouldn't let me, so I assumed it wouldn't be correct. Adding extra code

Comment: Or you could dispense with the member variable completely and pass the `RenderWindow` by reference to your `draw()` function. In any case, as @LogicStuff writes, you cannot copy a `RenderWindow` object. If you think about it hard enough, you'll understand why...

Comment: I edited the code again, how would I go about drawing the sprite

Comment: We use `->` to call a member function on an instance pointed-to by a pointer.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Solved.

Comment: @throwaway1234 solved? how about the real error